# A-Z Grid with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do grid like :

[A-Z Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5HaK.png)

Logic is very simple:
I get from Server array of Object. Each object have a few properties - one of them is Name

Next I just need to generate grid and put object under right Char

For example:
Items with nems- ABC, ADD,ANJ,ABYDT, etc... all them will under A

If I dont have for B items - so next will C

But I dont understan how to make this template(

Comment: which part are you having problems with ...html layout or how to repeat the data in view ?  Provide a sample of the data

Comment: Hard is how to render html with items under spec char
really - in evrything - i just dont know how to do it

Comment: Can use angular `groupBy`  https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/issues/57#issuecomment-65041792

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm looks great - thank you - I will try and write here about results